# C# LINQ update statement

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

So i work according to the LINQ model and want to do an update using the where statement but i don't know how to pass my 2 ids down...

This is my code...
The sc from my form:

```
tblEvk p= new tblEvk();
            p.fk_externvakID = currentCategoryId;
            p.fk_studentID = 2;
```

The bll:

```
 public void update(tblEvk p)
{
    DALstudent.update(p);
}
```

The DAL

```
 public void update(tblEvk s)
{
    var recordToUpdate = (from p in dc.tblEvks
                          where p.fk_studentID == id && p.fk_externvakID = vakid
                          select p).Single();

    recordToUpdate.evkBijlageGepost = 1;
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The question is how can i pass these variables? Using an insert i can just do public void insert (int id int vakid) but i cant do this with an update :(

Comment: I think it's just `where p.fk_studentID == s.fk_studentID && ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `id` and `vakid` are two properties of the entity `tblEvks` passed to the update method, then you can just do the following:

```
var recordToUpdate = (from p in dc.tblEvks
                          where p.fk_studentID == s.id && p.fk_externvakID = s.vakid
                          select p).Single();
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not I understand you right, but why not:

```
public void update(tblEvk s)
{
    var recordToUpdate = (from p in dc.tblEvks
                          where p.fk_studentID == s.fk_studentID && p.fk_externvakID = s.p.fk_externvakID
                          select p).Single();

    recordToUpdate.evkBijlageGepost = 1;
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```